# Traefik command line passing client ca

Tags: traefik

I am running traefik from rancher and would like to configure clientca certificate, I have mounted volume to container and run traefik with  '--entryPoints=Name:ops Address::90  tls.clientCA=/opt/clientca/ca.crt'.  Port 90 is opened but doesn't seem to require client certificate.

I am really confused how it could be passed: https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#traefik. Is that correct way?

Generating toml file could be also an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is not quite obvious sometimes. People expect options from configuration file to correspond one in command line, but it is not how it works at the moment. Basically as describe in [traefik entrypoint docs](https://github.com/containous/traefik/blob/master/docs/configuration/entrypoints.md#all-available-options) to achieve what you want, you need to specify "CA:" and "CA.optional" options like shown in examample below:

```
--entryPoints=Name:ops Address::90 TLS:{{ path_to_server_cert }},{{ path_to_server_key }} CA:{{ path_to_ca }} CA.Optional:false Compress:true
```

If you would like to use acme (let's encrypt) certificates instead of providing server certificate and key directly, you should use following command line

```
--entryPoints=Name:ops Address::90 TLS CA:{{ path_to_ca }} CA.Optional:false Compress:true
--acme.entrypoint=ops
```

As you may noticed, using acme certificates requires providing an entrypoint name using 
'**--acme.entrypoint=**'
 command line option. As for now (08.02.2019) there is no way to specify more than one entrypoint for using with acme. It means that if you are already using acme on different entrypoint you MUST provide server certificate and key directly to the entrypoint